# Copying last 3 elements of ArrayList into List<String>

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, copy

I am currently trying to no avail to copy the final 3 elements of each iterating path into `lastEdgePath`. Furthermore, `lastEdgePath` has to be of type `List < String >` . List of Arraylists `allPaths` works and for this question it is to be assumed that it is populated. This is what I tried, what is currently happening is that the last 3 elements are added as 1 into `lastEdgePath`, while I need them to be added as the 3 different elements they are. Example: if path is [1,2,3,4,5,6] `lastEdgePath` would become [4,5,6]

```
public static List<ArrayList<String>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

for(ArrayList<String> path : allPaths){
      List<String> lastEdgePath = Collections.singletonList(path.get(path.size() - 3) + path.get(path.size() - 2) + path.get(path.size() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subList`:

```
List<String> lastThreeThings = path.subList(path.size() - 3, path.size());
```

Note that this is a view of the underlying list, so changes to `lastThreeThings` are reflected in `path`. If you need a separate list, copy it:

```
List<String> lastThreeThings = new ArrayList<>(path.subList(path.size() - 3, path.size()));
```

Also, note that this doesn't handle a list shorter than 3 elements. If that's a possibility, use `Math.max(0, path.size() - 3)` as the start index.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the subList method.

```
public static List<ArrayList<String>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

for(ArrayList<String> path : allPaths){
      List<String> lastEdgePath = path.subList(path.size() - 3, path.size());
}
```

The one really important thing to note would be that this produces a **view of the specified range** meaning that any changes in the sublist will be reflected in the original list and vice versa.